# Calling a function pointer in my main function

Tags: c, list, struct, hashtable, function-pointers

So I am currently trying to test a function that I programmed that takes in a function pointer, and was wondering as to what the proper method was in calling it in main?

The current error I am getting is:
"warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'unsigned long' to
      parameter of type 'unsigned long (*)(char *)' [-Wint-conversion]"

Which I think I AM addressing with the way I am trying to call this function. Thank You!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct sll sll;
struct sll {
  char *s;
  sll *next;
};

struct hash_table {
  unsigned long int(*hash)(char *);
  unsigned int n_buckets;
  sll **buckets; /* an array of pointers to string lists */
};
typedef struct hash_table htbl;

unsigned long int good_hash(char *s) {
  unsigned long int init = 17;
  int i; // count                                                                              
  for (i = 0; i <= strlen(s) - 1; i++) {
    init = 37 * init + s[i];
   }
  return init;
}


htbl *ht_new(unsigned long int(*h)(char*), unsigned int sz) {
  htbl *nh;
  nh = malloc(sizeof(htbl));
  nh->hash = h;
  nh->buckets = malloc(sizeof(sll)*sz);
  return nh;
}



int main() {
unsigned long int(*functionPtr)(char*) = &good_hash;
char *fork = "FORK";
 printf("%s\n", ht_new((*functionPtr)(fork), 30)->buckets[16]->s);
}
```

Comment: `(*functionPtr)(fork)` is a function *call*. To pass the pointer, just use `functionPtr`.

Comment: So I tried doing that, but that gives me the same error (or warning I should say)

Comment: @LeehoLim: you can't have made the change.  You won't get that error if you call: `printf("%s\n", ht_new(functionPtr, 30)->buckets[16]->s);` but you will get the error if you leave the `(fork)` around.  You then have a design problem; you need to redesign the `ht_new` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ht_new((*functionPtr)(fork), 30)
```

This calls the function `functionPtr` points to, passing it `fork`, and then passes the result of that to `ht_new`.

What you want is just to pass `functionPtr` to `ht_new`:

```
ht_new(functionPtr, 30)
```

Comment: How would I then call "fork" with functionPtr?

Comment: @LeehoLim huh? You don't call strings.

Comment: You need to redesign the `ht_new()` function.  Or you need to forget about the fork in the `ht_new()` function.  I can't see how you'd use that value in the function.  In a `ht_insert()` function, it would matter.  But not in the `ht_new()`.

Comment: I mean my functionPtr points to a function, good_hash, which has one input of char* (a string). Where do I put the input? (Sorry, I didn't mean "call")

Comment: @LeehoLim If `ht` is a pointer to the hash table, then `(*ht->h)("FORK")` will call `good_hash` through the pointer (if the hash table was created by passing a pointer to `good_hash` to `ht_new`)